# Kafka: how could several options be picked up modulated by users via a menu or decision tree?

Tags: apache-kafka, menu, decision-tree, flink-streaming

I am grouping input data based on key, then doing 1 minute window with 30 seconds hop and in aggregator.

Data is being sent and consumed by an application, and the need for this application could evolve in the future, therefore, I see a need for future flexibility and quick change.

The current logic is described below:

```
@StreamListener("input")
    public void process(KStream<String, Data> DataKStream) {

        JsonSerde<DataAggregator> DataJsonSerde =
                new JsonSerde<>(DataAggregator.class);

        DataKStream
                .groupByKey()
                .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(60000).advanceBy(30000))
                .aggregate(
                        DataAggregator::new,
                        (key, Data, aggregator) -> aggregator.add(Data),
                        Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), DataJsonSerde)
                );
    }
DataAggregator.java

public class DataAggregator {

    private List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

    public DataAggregator add(Data data) {
        dataList.add(data.getId());
        System.out.println(dataList);
        return this;
    }

    public List<String> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

However, given evolving requirements I would like to give users the possibility to change the logic via a menu.

For example, users could change the window at wish or change the way data is segregated.

I was potentially thinking of writing several java classes which could be turned on and off when users pick specific options.

But I am wondering if something better and more dynamic could be done.

Comment: https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/01/15/demo-fraud-detection.html and https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/03/24/demo-fraud-detection-2.html present an example of how to build something like what you describe using Apache Flink.

Comment: Thank you! I will look it up! I gave it a quick look, and if understand correctly, via a front end in a react specific rules, streams and partitions can be selected? But the "rules" have to already have Flink job setup for each of the potential "views"? As described here: "The middle section is devoted to managing the rules evaluated by Flink. From here, you can create new rules as well as issue control commands, such as clearing Flink’s state."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Flink, some things can't be changed while a job is running -- notable, the topology of the job graph, and the parallelism of the operators.

On the other hand, a control stream can be broadcast throughout the cluster to effect dynamic changes to the business logic. In simple cases this has been used to modify filter parameters; in more complex cases it has been used, for example, to trigger dynamic loading of code or machine learning models (e.g., by broadcasting PMML) used in transformations.

Sample use cases: [RBEA: Scalable Real-Time Analytics at King](https://www.ververica.com/blog/rbea-scalable-real-time-analytics-at-king), [StreamING models, how ING adds models ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do7C4UJyWCM) .

What's less obvious is how dynamically reconfigure aggregations. The open source Fraud Detection Demo ([part 1](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/01/15/demo-fraud-detection.html), [part 2](https://flink.apache.org/news/2020/03/24/demo-fraud-detection-2.html), [github](https://github.com/afedulov/fraud-detection-demo)) illustrates how to accomplish that.

For another example, see [Cogynt: Flink without code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Av254WRuh70).